# How do I use distinct in FetchXml and not produce ambiguous results?

Tags: dynamics-crm, distinct, fetchxml

When I have the following FetchXml, how is the distinct='true' applied?  Does it refer to just the primary-entity record and should it return one record? Or given 4 linked-entity records which match the link-entity filter, should it return 4 records (i.e. should distinct-ness refer to the complete query)?

I have not been able to find any documentation which covers this nor have I found anything similar on SO.

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='primary-entity'>
    <attribute name='primary-entity-id />
    <attribute name='an-attribute'/>
    <filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute='an-attribute' operator='eq' value='something' />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='linked-entity' from='primary-entity' to='primary-entity-id' alias='le'>
      <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='an-attribute' operator='in'>
          <value>1</value>
          <value>2</value>
          <value>3</value>
          <value>4</value>
        </condition>
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "distinctness" refers to the complete query, or rather to all the attributes returned by the query. So if the link-entity records as in your case do not return any attributes, in effect the distinct should "cover" the primary entity only.